# while loop not working properly with ||

Tags: c, while-loop

I have the following code in C:

```
int main() {

    int num;

    printf("Enter 1, 2 or 3:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while(num != 1 || num != 2 || num != 3) {
        printf("Try again!\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The while loop never quits no matter what I enter. What is wrong with this bit of code?

When I enter num = 3 the while loop should be evaluated as false and it should not be executed. But for some reason it still is.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `||` means "if *any* of the conditions is true"...

Comment: For what you are gonna do, you should use AND

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ok, of course. I didn't notice that at first. :) How should I change the code that if one of the conditions is false (so num = 1, 2 or 3) the while loop won't be executed?

Comment: @AlessioMTX Ok, makes sense now. It's so simple but I wasn't thinking about that. Thanks guys! :)

Comment: @SomeOne you're welcome, but take a look to boolean algebra to clear your ideas ;)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you rather than changing your title to "SOLVED: *"

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I have to wait because there's time restriction . I will do that if it's allowed.

Comment: This is [basically a canonical duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/canonical-language-agnostic-question-for-ifvar-x-var-y), although nobody's yet agreed on what it's a dupe *of* exactly. Someone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your while loop condition is wrong. You need to use the AND operator `&&` instead of the OR operator `||`. When you use the OR operator, you're saying if any of these conditions are true, so in this case, if the input is not 1 or if it is not 2 or if it is not 3, you go into the loop again. This means that the input has to be equal to 1, 2, and 3 at the same time, which is impossible, hence the infinite loop.

I have seen this mistake a few times now; I think it is because people are used to using OR to mean "any", which works if the conditions being ORed are not negated. However, when you use it with negated conditions like `!(x==2)`, it means  all the conditions (like `x==2`)  must be true.This is DeMorgan's law in action, when you have a boolean expression of this form: `!x || !y || !z`, it is actually equivalent to `!(x && y && z)`, which evaluates to false only when all three conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple mistake! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your conditionals **intersect**.

Your first condition creates a group that has every number but `1`.
Your second condition creates a group that has every number but `2`.

According to logic rules, the `OR` operand is equivalent to **union** when working with groups, so:

`( Universe - {1} ) U ( Universe - {2} ) = Universe`

Basically your comparison will always be `true` with the first two conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

When using || in a condition it means: Return true if any of the conditions is true.
When using && in a condition it means: return true if all of the conditions are true.

So your solution is:

```
while(num != 1 && num != 2 && num != 3)
{
    // your code
}
```

Which means return true if num does not equal 1 AND does not equal 2 AND does not equal 3.